# How do I claim a post?

Tags: support, questions, answers, anonymous-user

I posted a few anonymous/guest answers before I signed up for Stack Overflow, and I'd like to "claim" them. Is there a way to claim posts that you made while not logged in?

If there isn't, can we have that feature? It'd be pretty easy to implement. When you sign up for a Stack Overflow account, all anonymous/guest posts with your email address will be transferred to your new account.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the email address(es) you used to post these, you can regain access to them easily using [the account recovery tool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery). Once recovered, just [request they be merged into your main account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

If you can't remember those emails, then you're probably out of luck. You can send us a list of the posts (use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page) & we'll see if there's any evidence they're yours, but I wouldn't get your hopes up.